# Unable to clear check from multi check

Tags: java, android

i have multi-check in my android program

Everything works great but there is one problem  - I can not uncheck all the markings

my code:

```
//============ fill the array ==============
CharSequence[] items={};
boolean[] itemsChecked;

SQL = "SELECT Name FROM Goods order by Name";
items = new String [16];
z=0;
try
{
   Cursor c = MyParam.db.rawQuery(SQL, null);
   if (c != null)
   {
         if (c.moveToFirst())
         {
            do
             {
              items[z++] = String.valueOf(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Name"))) ;
             }
             while (c.moveToNext());
          }
          c.close();
       }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
} 
itemsChecked = new boolean [items.length];


//======== when  i open the dialog ===========
btnGoods = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblGoods);
btnGoods.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
     public void onClick(View v)
     {
        DOD="";
        showDialog(1);
     }
 });


//================ i have this in my code - Not in used ===================
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
parent.setItemChecked(position, parent.isItemChecked(position));
}


//================== the dialog ================
@Override
protected  Dialog onCreateDialog(int id, Bundle args){
    switch(id){
            case 1:
                return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setTitle("Pick some")

                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int whichButton)
                {
                    DOD="";
                    for (int i=0;i<itemsChecked.length;i++)
                    {
                        if (itemsChecked[i]==true)
                        {
                            DOD+=items[i].toString() + ",";
                        }
                    }
                    DOD = DOD.substring(0,DOD.length()-1);
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),DOD, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                })

                .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int whichButton)
                {
                    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Cancel clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                })

                .setMultiChoiceItems(items, itemsChecked, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,boolean isChecked) {
                    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),items[which] + (isChecked ? " checked!":" unchecked!"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                }
                )
                .create();
```

its works excellent, but i cant uncheck all.

i try this:

```
DOD="";
itemsChecked = new boolean [items.length];
for (int i=0;i<itemsChecked.length;i++)
{
        itemsChecked[i]=false;
}
```

**EDIT:**

i try this also, and I managed to control the checkBox when i close the dialod

how to do it when the dialog load ?

```
.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int whichButton)
    {
          ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView().setItemChecked(2, true);
    }
    })
```

thanks

Comment: the piece of code you tried only sets to false every boolean in the itemsChecked array. You do nothing to items..

Comment: please format code above

Comment: how to update the Dialog  and uncheck all the checkbox ?

Comment: No one is having something similar and can help

Comment: I dug researched and still can not solve it, can someone please help ?

Comment: I dug researched and still can not solve it, can someone please help ?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way is to try getting the actual checkbox elements and using the toggle() or setSelected() method.

Comment: can i get sample for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try Using this:

```
((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView().setItemChecked(positioin, false);
```

Comment: you wil have to create a private class variable and assign it to the `Dialog` which is returned by `onCreateDialog()` so you can assign it inside `onCreateDialog()` and the return dialog object. and whenever you want to uncheck the items then, use the same for loop and use the code i posted.

Comment: something like this ??? protected  Dialog onCreateDialog(int id, Bundle args){
   switch(id){
   
   case 99:
    AlertDialog dialog = null;
    int positioin = 0;
    ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView().setItemChecked(positioin, false);